# Background thread in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 shopping application. I have a continously running thread in the app which downloads the users basket and saves it in a local cache to imporve performance.
So far what I have is something like this:

```
while(UserLoggedIn)
{
    await Networking.getBasket();
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

This thread is started when app resumes. My question is: What is the best approach to controll such a thread? On the app resuming it seems really slow, and sometimes it blocks the UI thread, although it's fully async. How can I improve performance?

**EDIT**

According to Romasz's suggestion, I used a Timer like this:

Declaring it:

```
Timer _getBasketTimer;
```

Initializing it in the App's constructor:

```
_getBasketTimer = new Timer(getBasketCallback, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Defining its callback:

```
private async void getBasketCallback(Object state)
{
    if (JSONCache.getSessionID() != "" && Networking.LoginInProgress == false)
        await Networking.getBasket();

    //The Change method may be called when the Timer object is already Disposed (I debugged it, and the exception did occur sometimes)
    try
    {
        _getBasketTimer.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    catch(ObjectDisposedException)
    {

    }
}
```

Disposing it in the App's Suspending event, so the Thread won't run when the App is suspended:

```
_getBasketTimer.Dispose();
```

And start it when the app is resuming:

```
_getBasketTimer = new Timer(getBasketCallback, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: Why not to use a timer with interval of 5 seconds and in its tick event check the basket?

Comment: I didn't know I can do something like this :) But it sounds cool!

Comment: @Romasz `Task.Delay` internally will use a timer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Another good day to learn something. Would you mind if I ask you few questions about this? What kind of timer it will use? Does it always work like this?

Comment: @Romasz Yes. [This](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,34b191a243434f6a) will answer your questions :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sorry for previous comment, but I've missed the link behind *This* in your comment. Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a something on a thread in intervals (also on thread other than UI one), you may use [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Timer(v=vs.110).aspx). A sample can look like this:

```
System.Threading.Timer myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (state) => { if (UserLoggedIn) await Task.Delay(1000); }, null, 0, 5 * 1000);
```

Note that if you would like to access UI elements from timer's Callback, then you will have to use *Dispatcher*.

Also don't forget to stop timers/cancel tasks once your app gets suspended, and resume them on resuming event, if still needed.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to tell without seeing more code, but you probably need to wrap your loop in a new thread to get it off the UI thread:

```
 Task.Run(async () =>
            {
               while(UserLoggedIn)
               {
                  await Networking.getBasket();
                  await Task.Delay(5000);
               }
            });
```